# how to make news widget in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a news site and some of my partners want to include latest news. They are doing that with iframe at the moment but they are asking for javascript version so that they can style div, please help me how do i do it in javascript ?

my current script is like this

```
<iframe height="30%" width="50%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://mysite.com/latestnews.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad IMO. First you have to think about how to retrieve the data (Ajax?). Then how to parse it, depending on the format, and extract the relevant information and then build the DOM. That's the gist of it.

Comment: it is html page coming from php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "they are asking for a JavaScript version" that could be interpreted as providing just the data and leaving it to your clients to add whatever html markup and styling that they like. If that's what you're asking about, then you could setup a page at your site that handles JSONP requests.

JSONP basically returns a JSON string, but wrapped in a JavaScript function call with a function name specified in the request. So let's say you add a new URL to your site, something like `http://mysite.com/newsfeed.php`. Your users would call it from their JavaScript code as:

```
http://mysite.com/newsfeed.php?callback=someFunction
```

And your server would return text:

```
someFunction('[{"title" : "news item title", "body" : "news item body here"},
               {"title" : "2nd item title", "body" : "2nd item body here"}]');
```

(Obviously you'd use whatever JSON structure makes sense for the way you store/present your news, but the key thing is the function name specified in the request gets echoed back out as part of the response.)

The PHP to output something like that isn't very complicated, just something like this:

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$data = array(array("title" => "news item title", "body" => "news item body here"),
              array("title" => "2nd item title", "body" => "2nd item body here"));

echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($data).')';
```

Obviously you wouldn't have hard-coded news items, you'd populate the `$data` array from your news database as appropriate.

You'd then provide two things to your partners: 1. the expected format of the JSONP request, which really is just the URL and the callback parameter name as shown above, and 2. the output format of the JSON - something similar to the above but presumably with dates, perhaps bylines, sources, whatever fields you have for each news item. The rest is up to them: there are several JS libraries that make JSONP calls easy, but presumably your partners can manage those details for themselves given that JSONP is fairly standard.